# MySQL Issue joining table with two columns against one

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a contacts table with id, first, last, and identification columns. Trying to get the names to display in a larger join. I cannot get it to display when joining both columns.

Tables:

Inspections
 Id
 Order_Id
 Inspector_Id

Contacts
 Id
 First_Name
 Last_Name
 Orderer
 Inspector

This is my SELECT:

```
$sql = " SELECT 
        Inspections.Id,     
        Inspections.Orderer_Id,
        Inspections.Inspector_Id,   
        Contacts.Id 
        Contacts.First_Name AS OFirst,
        Contacts.Last_Name AS OLast,
        Contacts.First_Name AS IFirst,
        Contacts.Last_Name AS ILast,

FROM Inspections
JOIN Contacts ON Inspections.Orderer_Id &&         Inspections.Inspector_Id=Contacts.Id
WHERE
                Inspections.Id = " . $trigger . ";";
```

This is just the latest attempt. I have tried numerous ways of joining them, but I guess I am just having a hard time translating the code I've found while searching. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are the values in all three columns the same? You would need to specify two separate expressions. As in `Inspections.orderer_id = Contacts.id AND inspections.inspector_id=contacts.id`. But if that is the case you want, I would suggest joining on only 1 and comparing `Inspections.orderer_id = Inspections.inspector_id` in the where clause.

Comment: Your join condition has invalid syntax: `Inspections.Orderer_Id` isn't a boolean expression, I believe you meant `Inspections.Orderer_Id =Contacts.Id`.  Also `&&` isn't valid SQL, you need to use `AND`

Comment: @jmoerdyk while `AND` is traditional for SQL, mysql does allow for `&&` and `||` in expressions. [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and)

Comment: Sorry, been working with MSSQL so long my MySQL is rusty :P

Comment: They Values in Orderer_Id and Inspector_Id both point to the Contacts.Id.

Comment: `JOIN Contacts ON Inspections.Orderer_Id = Contacts.Id &&         Inspections.Inspector_Id=Contacts.Id`

Comment: During an earlier process, The Contact is specified as one or the other, and then their Contact.Id is placed in the Inspections.Orderer_Id or Inspections.Inspector_Id field. I can get both to display their respective ID's but when going for Names...I just cant get it.

Comment: jmoerdyk, I've tried that variation before. Just tried yours as well directly. It "breaks" the SELECT.

Comment: Your query will only work if the `Inspector` and `Orderer` are the same person, if they are not, you have to join on `Contacts` twice using table aliases.

Comment: OK, So I've tried to use alias as well. such as: SELECT Contacts.Id AS OrdererId, Contacts.Id AS Inspector.Id, then How would I join correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your current query will only work (once the syntax errors are cleaned up) if the Inspector and Orderer are the same person, if they are not, you have to join on Contacts twice using table aliases:

```
 SELECT 
        Inspections.Id,     
        Inspections.Orderer_Id,
        Inspections.Inspector_Id,   
        orderer.Id AS OId,
        orderer.First_Name AS OFirst,
        orderer.Last_Name AS OLast,
        inspector.Id AS IId,
        inspector.First_Name AS IFirst,
        inspector.Last_Name AS ILast    
FROM Inspections
JOIN Contacts AS orderer ON Inspections.Orderer_Id = orderer.Id
JOIN Contacts AS inspector ON Inspections.Inspector_Id = inspector.Id
WHERE Inspections.Id = xxxx
```

Comment: OK, I see what you are going for here. I tried to directly input, and its a no go, but I have a question. How/Where are you declaring that the orderer.Id is actually the Contacts.Id? Same for Inspector. I see that those should be table aliases, but not sure how to set that. I will continue to search the web and play with your example. Thank you for your continued help!

Comment: Nevermind! I missed adding a "," after the ILast. (I have further SELECTS after. This worked perfectly. THANKS A MILLION! I dont have enough rep to mark as Answered, but you nailed it.

Comment: In the JOIN condition, you set the alias in the query after the table name.  I've updated the query to make it clearer, the name after the `AS` sets the alias for the table before the `AS`.  Most SQL servers allow you to omit the `AS` keyword.